# Application non showing in global Quick Search Box

Tags: android

I want to create a simple app which shows infos on the global quick search box in android.

I did follow some howtos but i can't get my app in the menu "Settings->Search->Searchable Items" which is the menu that let the user check which suggestions he wants in the QSB.

I can attach the manifest here and the searchable xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.andreabaccega.marketsearch" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".Init" android:label="LUPO">

   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>

   <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
  </activity>
  <provider android:name="com.andreabaccega.marketsearch.SuggestionProvider"
   android:authorities="com.andreabaccega.marketsearch.SuggestionProvider" android:syncable="false"/>
 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

This is the searchable.xml file

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:label="Teasdst"
 android:searchSettingsDescription="asd asd asd"
 android:includeInGlobalSearch="true" 
 android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.andreabaccega.marketsearch.SuggestionProvider"
 android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW" 
 android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.andreabaccega.marketsearch.SuggestionProvider/"
  >

</searchable>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this might work:
in the searchable.xml remove any hardcoding of strings and all references to strings should be made as @string/yourString.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I've just debugged my app for 2 hours and it was this that was wrong.